Explanation for occurence of geometric isomerism in alkenes but not alkanes
I was reading through my chemistry textbook on isomerism for organic compounds (simple alkanes and alkenes). It explained structural isomerism for organic compounds and geometric stereoisomerism for alkenes.
In the geometric stereoisomerism topic, using cis-but-$2$-ene and trans-but-$2$-ene as an example, it stated the following:

Geometric isomerism can exist in alkenes but not alkanes. This is because there needs to be a C=C double bond for cis- and trans-isomers to occur. The presence of a C=C double bond leads to restricted rotation so that there cannot be any rotation around the double bond. The groups attached to each C in C=C can only be in one of two positions. However, in alkanes — which do not have any double bonds — carbon atoms and their attached groups can rotate freely (without restriction).

My question is: what does the rotation factor about the double or single bond have anything to do with the occurrence of geometric isomers when groups can either rotate (about single bonds) or swap (by being in any one of two positions) to form a geometric isomer? For example, $1$-fluoro-$2$-chloroethane can appear in these two versions as:

Isn't this a pair of cis- and trans- isomers for an alkane?

Since rotation of the c-c single bond is possible, v1 can rotate and become v2. Thus they are effectively the same. They are called conformational isomers and not cis trans/geometrical isomers.

You forgot is a single bond, which is rotating at ambient conditions.

It is worth looking into the conformations/rotamers of alkanes (ethane is a good place to start), which should also help you understand that example and any further examples.

Oh right, thanks @Nightwing
